# paypal personal account payment integration with flask

Tags: python, flask, paypal

I am developping a website using flask and I want to get user payments with Paypal.

For testing purpose, I want to let users pay a small amount using paypal, which will be converted into credits of website. **I don't have a PayPal business account.**

However, I failed to find a detailed and updated example to do this using flask and paypal: the ones I found them seem to be outdated or deprecated, such as [paypalrestsdk](https://pypi.org/project/paypalrestsdk/).

Also, PayPal's examples are in nodejs/javascript and most of them require a business account.

I noticed that one can easily create a paypal button and embed it in your own website. But how can we detect and verify using flask if we do it this way?

Do you have any suggestions or any other alternatives? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

PayPal payments can only be received with a business account.

In sandbox you can use an account from https://developer.paypal.com/dashboard/accounts . Log in to the developer dashboard with any live PayPal account, and manage your sandbox accounts for testing at that location. Those sandbox accounts can then be used at [www.sandbox.paypal.com](http://www.sandbox.paypal.com) for all your development needs.

---

For live payments, a live business account is required. Upgrading to a live business account is free and there is no reason not to do so when you are ready to receive payments in live mode.

Comment: Can I possibly test the website and ask users to transfer money to my personal account like we normally do to our friends? Another question is that if I use a business account, that means I have to register a company first, which seems to be an overkill if I only want to test my website. If the website fails to provide its purpose, it's difficult to close the company and also I suppose it generates lots of unwanted company related fees.

Comment: You would not be testing commercial PayPal payments, there would be no point. "I have to register a company first" -- as far as I know this requirement might only exist in your own mind but I cannot speak for every jurisdiction